# Express.js - display a custom 404 page when a record is not found in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am using [node-mongodb-native](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/) driver. I tried

```
collection.findOne({email: 'a@mail.com'}, function(err, result) {
  if (!result) throw new Error('Record not found!');
});
```

But the error is caught by mongodb driver and the express server is terminated.

What's the correct way for this case?

=== Edit===

I have the code below in app.js

```
app.configure('development', function() {
    app.use(express.errorHandler({dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true}));
});

app.configure('production', function() {
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
});
```

Related code in `node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js`

```
connectionPool.on("message", function(message) {
    try {
        ......
    } catch (err) {
      // Throw error in next tick
      process.nextTick(function() {
        throw err; // <-- here throws an uncaught error
      })
    }      
});
```

Comment: What kind of Object is `app`? Is it an `http` server, `express` server or something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct use is not to throw an error, but to **pass it** to `next` function. First you define the error handler:

```
app.error(function (err, req, res, next) {
    res.render('error_page.jade');
})
```

(What's this talk about `error` being depracated? I don't know anything about that. But even if then you can just use `use`. The mechanism is still the same.).

Now in your route you pass the error to the handler like this:

```
function handler(req, res, next) {
    collection.findOne({email: 'a@mail.com'}, function(err, result) {
        if (!result) {
            var myerr = new Error('Record not found!');
            return next(myerr); // <---- pass it, not throw it
        }
        res.render('results.jade', { results: result });
    });
};
```

Make sure that no other code (related to the response) is fired after `next(myerr);` (that's why I used `return` there).

**Side note:** Errors thrown in asynchronous operations are not handled well by Express (well, actually they somewhat are, but that's not what you need). This may crash your app. The only way to capture them is by using

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
    // handle it here, log or something
});
```

but this is a global exception handler, i.e. you cannot use it to send the response to the user.

Comment: This works! Regarding `app.error` being depracated in 3.x, I read it somewhere but I forgot where it is. In the side note, you said "Errors thrown in asynchronous operations are not handled well by Express". So are there any potential problems if I use your solution before the side note?

Comment: Why have you called `next` instead of rendering the error page directly from the callback? I could understand if the error handler were huge, but for a simple case like this are there any advantages? Just trying to improve my Express knowledge. :)

Comment: @meloncholy - I would like a single place to handle all errors, including runtime errors and those thrown explicitly in the app.

Comment: @meloncholy Because you may want to throw the very same exception in many routes. Rendering error page will be much easier to handle with error handler.

Comment: @powerboy There will be no problems, because in the solution you don't **throw** an exception, you **pass it**. :) Problems are only when you **throw** an exception in asynchronous code.

Comment: @powerboy freakish Thanks. So far I've had relatively few routes and often unique errors, but I should definitely consider this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the error is not caught. Are you using an Express error handler? Something like:

```
app.error(function (err, req, res, next) {
 res.render('error-page', {
  status: 404
 });
```

More on error handling in Express: http://expressjs.com/guide.html#error-handling

Comment: `app.error` is deprecated. Use `app.use` instead. Anyway, both do not work for my case. It might be related to mongodb driver.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of checking for errors off mongodb, use '!error' for success as opposed to '!result' for errors.

```
collection.findOne({email: 'a@mail.com'}, function(err, result) {
    if (!error) {
        // do good stuff;
    } else {
        throw new Error('Record not found!');
    }
});
```

As for the custom 404, I've yet to do that in node and express, but I would imagine it would involve "app.router".

Comment: I tried this. Actually, if mongodb cound not find the record, `result` becomes `null` while `err` is not set.

Comment: Strange. I just tried this with my app - it threw me the error for a record that didn't exist but both mongodb and express continue running. I did no handling, so it gave me a 500 page with the stack trace.